# When are cookies deleted for Twilio calls?

Tags: django, twilio

Twilio says that when it makes requests to my web application, it behaves "just like a web browser" and accepts HTTP cookies and sends them with every request. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/your_response

I have been running some tests and discovered that this isn't entirely true. Twilio remembers cookies in some cases and not others. I'm writing an application that uses the Conference noun of the Dial verb. My application works, but I noticed a lack of persistence after a conference finished.

My tests revealed that any cookies (or in my case database-backed sessions using Django) are forgotten after the view that has a conference. Can anyone confirm that cookies lack persistence after a conference has finished? And if so, how would one get around this problem? This seems like a serious flaw in what Twilio claims it is capable of.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Could you describe the test you say fails? Or show some code for it? Would love to understand what's going on here.

Comment: @philnash A support ticket from Twilio helped me understand what was happening. Conferences are an outgoing call (a `Dial` verb with a nested `Conference` noun); thus when the caller is connected to a conference, a response comes from Twilio, which in turn makes a request (in this case to the "Hold" view waiting room). The cookie set in the conference view does not keep in the hold view, and that was messing me up. TwiML is usually used to create a basic response, but it can make additional requests to the REST API, which is abstracted away. Would love to know if my thinking is off, though.

Comment: Sounds like the support team have done the job there. I'd still be interested in your code (or a minimal case) so I could understand too. If you've got time, drop me a line at philnash@twilio.com.